# Triceps easier exercices

Tags: calisthenics, triceps

Since lock-down, I switched my training to calisthenics. I did diamond push-ups (3x10) but it was too much. I completed it at the time but, the next day my triceps weren't able to support weight.

How can i make the exercise easier, or replace it with an easier triceps exercise ?

In the gym, I use to cable pull about 25 kg with both arms. By the way, I don't have any fitness material at home beside a rower.

I am 42 and weighting 169 lbs.

Here is my upper body training : 3 times a week, with at least one rest day.
Rest between sets are about 1 to 2 minutes depending on the exercise.

- 3x10 Hand over head pushups
- 6x10 Front Raise (for each arms) (using my home rower about 18lbs)
- 3x10 Wide pushups
- 3x10 Pike pushups (focus Delt)
- 6x10 Biceps curls (for each arms) (using my home rower about 22lbs)
- 3x10 Diamond pushups
- 3x24 Pike shoulder taps
- 1x24 Hyperextension

Next day at the park : (I don't have a pull-ups bar)

- 6x8 Pull-ups, if failure fallback to jumping pull-ups
- 3x  Hanging to the bar for 20 breaths
- 6x8 Australian pull-ups

Thanks,

Comment: My guess is that if you take two rest days you will have no problem continuing with the diamond push-ups. After a few weeks you will then only need 1 rest day. Muscles need rest to grow. An exercise you can do 10 reps of is not too hard. 10 reps is recommended for hypertrophy and 5 for strength.

Comment: If you insist on an easier exercise; maybe you could do the push-ups against something slightly elevated such as the end of a sofa.

Comment: If you were able to do 3x10, you shouldn't go to an easier exercise. You are strong enough to do the diamond push up, why make your training less effective? I would look at other variables here: How much do you rest between sests? Why do you do the same thing again the next day? How long have you been training? What other stuff do you do and in what order? How much do you eat and sleep? What do you eat? How much do you drink? Well, that is unless you have a very good reason for what you are doing. Are you working to a very specific goal here?

Comment: @Raditz_35 its part of upper body training, which includes pull ups, other type of pushups and some other exercises. But yesterday, I did 3x8 diamond pushups and no problem today. I put my hand at chest level, but the last time it was lower than the plexuses, I discover it's much harder. Usually when I train other muscles to failure or near failure it’s not a problem. But with triceps, it comes later and when they are weak, it prevents you from doing certain exercises. Maybe I am over training them?

Comment: I have added my upper body training so you could see

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Why that routine? I'm serious, I suspect something here, please explain. Where did you get it from? Why those numbers? Where do you go from there? Aso: Do you incorporate progressive overload in some shape or form? And please also include how long you've been doing this in total and specifically without any significant change (basically = progressive overload).

Comment: Well, I took my gym program and try to "convert it" to target the same muscles whenever possible. Also my goal is hypertrophy. I started in August 2019. At beginning of the lockdown I was doing 8 reps per set instead of 10 and much fewer pull-ups. When an exercise feels too easy, I try to make it harder, e.g.: I replaced normal pushups by wide one. That’s how I am trying to do progressive overload.

Comment: I think you do too many push-ups and are overtrained. You should decrease the total number of sets of push-ups, not the intensity. Maybe you could use an elastic band around your back to make the push-ups harder and then just do ordinary push-ups instead of both wide and diamond. Alternatively you could make the push-ups harder by elevating your feet slightly.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do 3x8 instead of 3x10 for pushups and see how it goes. thx

Comment: Sorry, but let's go there: why do you do 3x10 diamond pushups 3 times a week? By that I mean why 3, why 10, why diamond pushups, why 3 times a week. I could of course ask that about everything. That you had some other routine that you "converted" may be 100% correct, but I don't know what that means and if it is. Btw, you could try doing your diamond pushups in the beginning or maybe exchange them with the variation that seems easiest to you. Of course you're tired once you get to them

Comment: @Raditz_35 The upper body training that I was doing aim to muscle arms, pecs, back and shoulders insisting on shoulders. As I understand standard push-ups target pecs, triceps and shoulders. But I am trying to replace cable front pull-down with diamond push-ups, chest press machine with wide push-ups,  fly delts with over head push-ups and military press machine with pike push-ups.

Comment: Please take no offense, I'm just trying to get to the bottom of this: since you can't answer my questions directly, I'm assuming that you don't know the answer. Most people don't. And since you're doing 3x10, I'm assuming you read somewhere that's what you do and so you do it without any questions. You've also tried to replace one exercise that is meant to be targeting one thing with a bodyweight exercise that also is said to be for that muscle without considering that one might be harder. Am I correct? If so, you might need an explanation for the reasons behind some dogmas you are following

Comment: @Raditz_35 The question about 3x10 looks philosophical to me. When I created this workout, I wanted to challenge myself. 8 reps and then 10 reps seams enough, because it was between the 6 to 12 reps range for hypertrophy. If you have other as aspects to share go ahead, thx

Answer (score 2):

there are a few ways you could modify your push ups to lighten the load

1. You can perform the push up from your knees instead of from your toes like the classic push up
2. you can do a push up but instead of from the floor, you use like a bench or a chair that wont move so that you are not going parallel to the floor, but rather at an angle.

also, you can try doing dips as well. these are great and there are also many ways to modify them to make them easier/harder

from your routine though, you seem to be getting a lot of different push exercises in already, so perhaps you are just fatigued. maybe try to de-load for a week or so to let your body rest and then start back up again